# removing iterated string from string array

Tags: python, arrays, string, loops, system

I am writing a small script that lists the currently connected hard disks on my machine. I only need the disk identifier(disk0), not the partition ID(disk0s1, disk0s2, etc.)
How can I iterate through an array that contains diskID and partitionID and remove the partitionID entries? Here's what I'm trying so far:

```
    import os

    allDrives = os.listdir("/dev/")
    parsedDrives = []

    def parseAllDrives():
        parsedDrives = []
        matching = []
        for driveName in allDrives:
            if 'disk' in driveName:
                parsedDrives.append(driveName)
            else:
                continue
        for itemName in parsedDrives:
            if len(parsedDrives) != 0:
                if 'rdisk' in itemName:
                    parsedDrives.remove(itemName)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue

#### this is where the problem starts: #####

        # iterate through possible partition identifiers
        for i in range(5):
            #create a string for the partitionID
            systemPostfix = 's' + str(i)
            matching.append(filter(lambda x: systemPostfix in x, parsedDrives))

        for match in matching:
            if match in parsedDrives:
                parsedDrives.remove(match)
                print("found a mactch and removed it")

        print("matched: %s" % matching)
        print(parsedDrives)

    parseAllDrives()
```

That last bit is just the most recent thing I've tried. Definitely open to going a different route.

Answer (score 0):

try beginning with

```
allDrives = os.listdir("/dev/")
disks = [drive for drive in allDrives if ('disk' in drive)]
```

then, given disks id's are only 5-chars length

```
short_disks = [disk[:6] for disk in disks]
unique_short_disks = list(set(short_disks))
```

Comment: There are some disks however that contain a 2 digit identifier (i.e. disk11)

Comment: Ok, then you can filter them with `[disk[:7] ...]` first and then check last element of them by `not unique_short_disk[-1].isalpha()` _here [-1] refers to last element, `isalpha()` checks if it is letter, not number_.